# Using BeautifulSoup to find a tag and evaluate whether it fits some criteria

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program to extract text from a website and write it into a text file.  Each entry in the text file should have 3 values separated by a tab.  The first value is hard-coded to XXXX, the 2nd value should initialize to the first item on the website with , and the third value is the next item on the website with a .  The logic I'm trying to introduce is looking for the first  and write the associated string into the text file.  Then find the next  and write the associated string into the text file.  **Then, look for the next p class.  If it's "style4", start a new line, if it's another "style5", write it into the text file with the first style5 entry but separated with a comma (alternatively, the program could just skip the next style5.**

I'm stuck on the part of the program in bold.  That is, getting the program to look for the next p class and evaluate it against style4 and style5.  Since I was having problems with finding and evaluating the p class tag, I chose to pull my code out of the loop and just try to accomplish the first iteration of the task for starters. Here's my code so far:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kcda.org/KCDA_Awarded_Contracts.htm').read())
next_vendor = soup.find('p', {'class': 'style4'})
print next_vendor
next_commodity = next_vendor.find_next('p', {'class': 'style5'})
print next_commodity
next = next_commodity.find_next('p')
print next
```

I'd appreciate any help anybody can provide!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: So should your output be a tab separated file of vendor and category?

Comment: Yes.  I just didn't include that part of the code because I've got too many other hurdles to get over before I'm anywhere close to writing things to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure how you are expecting your output to be. I am assuming that you are trying to get the data in the webpage in the format:

```
Alphabet \t Vendor \t Category
```

You can do this:

```
# The basic things
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kcda.org/KCDA_Awarded_Contracts.htm').read())
```

Get the `td` of interest:

```
table = soup.find('table')
data = table.find_all('tr')[-1]
data = data.find_all('td')[1:]
```

Now, we will create a nested output dictionary with alphabets as the keys and an inner dict as the value. The inner dict has vendor name as key and category information as it's value

```
output_dict = {}
current_alphabet = ""
current_vendor = ""
for td in data:
    for p in td.find_all('p'):
        print p.text.strip()
        if p.get('class')[0] == 'style6':
            current_alphabet = p.text.strip()
            vendors = {}
            output_dict[current_alphabet] = vendors
            continue
        if p.get('class')[0] == 'style4':
            print "Here"
            current_vendor = p.text.strip()
            category = []
            output_dict[current_alphabet][current_vendor] = category
            continue
        output_dict[current_alphabet][current_vendor].append(p.text.strip())
```

This gets the output_dict in the format:

```
{   ...

    u'W': { u'WTI - Weatherproofing Technologies': [u'Roofing'],
            u'Wenger Corporation': [u'Musical Instruments and Equipment'],
            u'Williams Scotsman, Inc': [u'Modular/Portable Buildings'],
            u'Witt Company': [u'Interactive Technology']
        },
    u'X': { u'Xerox': [u"Copiers & MFD's", u'Printers']
        }
}
```

Skipping the earlier parts for brevity. Now it is just a matter of accessing this dictionary and writing out to a tab separated file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you for the thorough response!

Comment: @Nanashi There was an accept on this a while ago. Sigh!

Comment: Eh? Maybe user double-clicked and forgot. What a bummer. Very nice approach what you have. Hopefully he comes back to accept again.

Comment: @Shaktimaan There is a check again - I'm still figuring out the whole "choose one answer" part of the website.  In reality I really like both yours and Nanashi's responses - both work very nicely and elegantly.  Thank you both for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @shaktimaan. Using a dictionary or list is a good approach here. My attempt is slightly different.

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import csv

url = "http://www.kcda.org/KCDA_Awarded_Contracts.htm"
r = rq.get(url)
soup = bsoup(r.content)

primary_line = soup.find_all("p", {"class":["style4","style5"]})
final_list = {}
for line in primary_line:
    txt = line.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
    if txt != "\xc2\xa0":
        if line["class"][0] == "style4":
            key = txt
            final_list[key] = []
        else:
            final_list[key].append(txt)

with open("products.csv", "wb") as ofile:
    f = csv.writer(ofile)
    for item in final_list:
        f.writerow([item, ", ".join(final_list[item])])
```

For the scrape, we isolate `style4` and `style5` tags right away. I did not bother going for the `style6` or the alphabet headers. We then get the text inside each tag. If the text is not a whitespace of sorts (this is all over the tables, probably obfuscation or bad mark-up), we then check if it's `style4` or `style5`. If it's the former, we assign it as a key to a blank list. If it 's the latter, we append it to the blank list of the most recent key. Obviously the key changes every time we hit a new `style4` only so it's a relatively safe approach.

The last part is easy: we just use `", ".join` on the value part of the key-value pair to concatenate the list as one string. We then write it to a CSV file.

Due to the dictionary being unsorted, the resulting CSV file will not be sorted alphabetically. Screenshot of result below:

[image]

Changing it to a tab-delimited file is up to you. That's simple enough. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your response!  This is also a great solution!  I really do wish I could select multiple answers to this question since both responses are elegant and work great!  Thanks again!